# Finding the exact name of City and Country

Tags: python, python-3.x, geospatial, osmnx

```py
import osmnx as ox
%matplotlib inline
G = ox.graph_from_place('Seoul, South Korea', network_type='drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))
```

In this part, how to find the exact title of city and country? It does not work for Seoul, South Korea.

I have tried a few times but it was failed.

```py
import osmnx as ox
%matplotlib inline
G = ox.graph_from_place('Seoul, South Korea', network_type='drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper solution to the name problem, but a useful workaround is to use lat/lon coordinates as parameters in [`ox.graph_from_point()`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.graph_from_point):

```
G = ox.graph_from_point([37.5666791, 126.9782914],
                        distance=30000,
                        network_type='drive')
```

and you get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a specific issue with Seoul as I tried it for other cities and areas and it worked. 
In that case you can try combine graphs of areas inside the city or as Sentence answered to use coordinates or even bbox.